# How to calculate the degree of a polynomial in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I need to create a scheme code that allows me to calculate the degree of a polynomial and show it, is there a special function in scheme that allows me to treat them?

pd:  What is the way to raise these types of problems?

Comment: How is the polynomial represented as data? If it needs to be represented as a function value it's probably not possible, since functions are mostly black boxes that you can only call with arguments. But if you can come up with a Data Definition for polynomials that includes that information in a more transparent way, then it's possible. So how are you representing the polynomials as data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function just like there are no functions for guns in games in the standard libraries. There isn't even one data structure for a polynomial.

As with all user defined extensions you have the power to model your data as you wish and you make an interface to work with that data. This is how you extend the language to support the data you want to play with.

```scm
;; this is not part of the interface
(define tag-point (list 'point))

;; these are the interface
(define (point x y)
  (list tag-point x y))

(define point-x cadr)
(define point-y caddr)

(define (point? p)
  (and (pair? p)
       (eq? (car p) tag-point)))

;; implemented distance that uses the interface
(define (distance p1 p2)
  ;; (assert (and (point? p1) (point? p2)))
  (sqrt (+ (square (- (point-x p1) (point-x p2)))
           (square (- (point-y p1) (point-y p2))))))

(distance (point 3 0 ) (point 0 4)) ; ==> 5
```

Now you can change your data structure as long as the interface stays intact:

```scm
;; implement points using complex numbers
(define (point x y) (make-rectangular x y))    
(define (point-x p) (real-part p))
(define (point-y p) (imag-part p))
(define (point? p) (complex? p))
```

One could just do `(define point make-rectangular)` but then the interface documentation would be vague.

In the [SICP videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46) I remember they did a polynomial type. It's in [part 4B](https://youtu.be/h6Z7vx9iUB8). It explains pretty much the same as I do here and they actually implement polynomials as a type you can do arithmetic on. Thus it might not be what you are looking for, but their data structure can give you an idea.